# Synchronize clocks between server and client with React-Native / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, react-native, date, synchronization, clock

I'm working on React-Native project.
I need to precisely synchronize clocks (≃40ms) between server and mobile clients. I need to trigger an action simultaneously on the different clients.
The timing of the trigger may be less accurate, there may be a delay (1-3s), but must be precisely synchronized (≃40ms).
Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: I try with NTP servers.Someone already used react-native-clock-sync, or react-native-ntp-client. I sometimes have lags (100 -800ms) that appear. I cannot identify the source of the problem.